# Outlook Exchange Service Email Watcher

Tags: node.js, email, outlook, listener, exchange-server-2010

I want to get some notification that a new mail has arrived to your inbox and its details. so basically i need a listener to mailbox. just like we have file watcher / remote SFTP watcher and others utilities like that.

Please suggest me a solution for this . it can be in any framework ( Node.js, .NET etc )

Heard about outlook push subscriptions but i am not clear with them.
I am able to programmatically read every mail from exchange server using .NET . i don't want that , i need a listener